# jQuery UI DatePicker must NOT submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using a jQuery UI Datepicker, however when someone click the calendar icon, it "submit" the form, which is not a wanted behavior.

I was able to cancel it by controlling the click property of my calendar icon(the one bound to the jQuery UI CSS-styled Calendar) with this:

```
$('.datePicker').click(
   function ($e) {
       $e.preventDefault();
   });
```

However I am quite sure that there must be cleaner way to fix this issue. It would help me quite a lot if someone could answer this

Thanks !

EDIT:
To answer the comments...

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('.datePicker').each(function () {
        $(this).datepicker();
        var x = $.trim('#' + $(this).attr('id').split('_')[0]);
        $('#' + $(this).attr('id')).datepicker("option", "altField", x);
        $('#' + $(this).attr('id')).datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");
    });
    $('.datePicker').click(
       function ($e) {
           $e.preventDefault();
       });
});
```

Code generated by .NET:

```
<input type=\"text\" id=\"{0}\" class=\"datePickerText\" style=\"width:80px\">
<input type=\"image\" src=\"/Content/images/calendrier.png\" id=\"{0}_IconeDatePicker\" class=\"datePicker\">
```

Where {0} is the ID parameter.

Comment: Can you show the html code for the form?

Comment: Default jQueryUI datepicker markup would just have them clicking `<a>` which shouldn't submit a form. What other markup and/or js have you written?

Comment: Why you don't use `asp:Image` control or even `img` tag instead of `ImageButton`?

Comment: I did try img tag but it doesn't work... When I click on it, nothing happens

Comment: You incorrectly use datepicker plugin. It must be applied against `text` input whereas you applying it on button.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
$(function () {
    $('.datePicker').each(function () {
        $(this).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "/Content/images/calendrier.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
    });
});
```

Simply had to use the button options of the API :)